# Package a Maven-transformed web.xml in the final war

Tags: xml, maven

I want to make Maven process the `web.xml` file prior to including it in the final *war*. This is going to be profile-dependent, so editing the source XML is not an option.

I'm using the `xml-maven-plugin` to add the new elements to the file (you can get additional details in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25957167/3127111)), and had success in achieving it, having the plugin put the trasformed file in `target/generated-resources/xml/xslt` (I guess that's a default destination directory).

Now I need to instruct Maven to pick up that transformed file (and not the one in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/`) when packaging the application.

But I'm stuck here, I have no idea how to go further.

As a side note, I bound the `xml-maven-plugin` to the `process-resources` phase.
The whole plugin configuration follows at the end.

Feel free to suggest another folder structure, configuration changes, or even if this isn't the right way to do it, etc — this is a test setup, I'm using it to learn Maven.

```xml
    <profile>
        <id>release-production</id>
        <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault></activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xml-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>transform</goal>
                            </goals>
                             <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>

                    <configuration>
                        <transformationSets>
                            <transformationSet>
                                <dir>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</dir>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>web.xml</include>
                                </includes>
                                <stylesheet>src/main/resources-xml/webxml-transform.xsl</stylesheet>
                            </transformationSet>
                        </transformationSets>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

---

I already saw the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14366116/3127111) to the question: [How to transform web.xml during packaging with maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14350349/3127111), but I need to add whole XML elements to the `web.xml`, so I guess that using properties won't work here (at least, I had an error when I tried to define a property with XML content).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was easier than I thought (although I guess this could be done with a simpler configuration).
I'm open to suggestions, of course.

### First step: configure a custom output directory for the xml transformer

The xml-maven-plugin has an (undocumented?) additional property: [`<outputDir />`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/xml-maven-plugin/apidocs/org/codehaus/mojo/xml/transformer/TransformationSet.html#setOutputDir(java.io.File)) in its `TransformationSet` element (here's my full plugin configuration).

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>xml-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>transform</goal>
            </goals>
             <phase>process-resources</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>

    <configuration>
        <transformationSets>
            <transformationSet>
                <dir>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</dir>
                <includes>
                    <include>web.xml</include>
                </includes>
                <stylesheet>src/main/resources-xml/webxml-transform.xsl</stylesheet>
                <outputDir>target/generated-resources</outputDir>
            </transformationSet>
        </transformationSets>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

### Second step: configure the *war* plugin to read another web.xml file

Tell the maven-war-plugin where the new (transformed) `web.xml` file is:

Having bound the `xml-maven-plugin` to the *process-resources* phase, I know that the transformed `web.xml` will be there when the *war* is packaged.

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>

    <configuration>
        <webXml>target/generated-resources/web.xml</webXml>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```